# Complex representations of groups of invertible elements in finite local rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, local-rings, unitary-representations

Let $R$ be a finite local $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra, and let $J$ be its Jacobson radical. Assume that $R/J\cong \mathbb{F}_p$, and assume that the socle of $R$ as an $R$-bimodule is one dimensional over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Write $z$ for a basis element of the socle. Consider the $p$-group $G=1+J\subseteq R^{\times}$, and assume that $1+z\in [G,G]$.

**Question**: is it true that if $V$ is an irreducible complex representation of $G$ on which $1+z$ acts non-trivially, then $V$ is induced from a representation of subgroup of the form $1+(J\cap S)$, where $S$ is some subring of $R$?